# Expression evaluation, objects from string... still not clear

Tags: r, expression, evaluation, tidyverse

I've read many topic on how to create objects from strings or evaluate expressions, with `assign()`, `get()`, `as.name()` or `eval(substitute())`, but some things are not completely clear to me.

In my example below, I have one dataset in input (long format), and I want 3 matrices in output.

The input dataframe :

```
# Input dataframe
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)),
                 v2 = c(rep(letters[1:3], 2)),
                 dfA = sample(1:10, 6),
                 dfB = sample(1:10, 6),
                 dfC = sample(1:10, 6))

> df
  v1 v2 dfA dfB dfC
1  A  a   5  10   5
2  A  b   4   7   9
3  A  c  10   1   2
4  B  a   7   9   7
5  B  b   2   8   1
6  B  c   9   3   4
```

The prefix of 3 variables is the dataset name (and then "A", "B", "C").

When spreading with `v2` as key, I want 3 matrices with respectively `dfA`, `dfB` and `dfC` values.
The matrices names will have the name of the spread values too.
Row names will be the `v1` values.

Matrices I want :

```
> dfA
  a b c
A 4 1 2
B 5 8 7

> dfB
   a b c
A  1 9 5
B 10 4 2

> dfC
  a b c
A 5 1 3
B 6 4 9
```

So, manually, no problem to do it (I just do the first matrix here) :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfA            <- df %>% select(v1, v2, dfA) %>% spread(key = v2, value = dfA)
row.names(dfA) <- dfA[, 1]
dfA            <- dfA %>% select(-1) %>% as.matrix()


> dfA
  a b c
A 4 1 2
B 5 8 7
```

But now, I have many dataframes in input so I want to do it automatically.
I'll do a function with the DF name as argument, but now I want to show you step by step without function.

```
dfName = "df"

# For : dfA <- df %>% select(v1, v2, dfA) :
assign(paste0(dfName, "A"), get(dfName) %>% select(v1, v2, get(paste0(dfName, "A"))))

> dfA
  v1 v2 dfA
1  A  a   5
2  A  b   4
3  A  c  10
4  B  a   7
5  B  b   2
6  B  c   9


# For : dfA <- dfA %>% spread(key = v2, value = dfA)
assign(paste0(dfName, "A"), get(paste0(dfName, "A")) %>%
 spread(key = v2, value = get(paste0(dfName, "A"))))

Error: Invalid column specification
```

There, I have an error with the spread function.
It worked in the `select()` above, but not in the spread()... how should I have done it ?

Well, the only way I manage to do it is :

```
eval(substitute(var1 <- var1 %>% spread(key = v2, value = var1),
                list(var1 = as.name(paste0(dfName, "A")))))

> dfA
  v1 a b  c
1  A 5 4 10
2  B 7 2  9
```

Then, I want to put v1 values into row.names :

```
row.names(get(paste0(dfName, "A"))) <- get(paste0(dfName, "A"))[, 1]
```

... the error (I don't get it) :

```
Error in ... could not find function "get<-"
```

But I managed to do it this way :

```
eval(substitute(row.names(var1) <- var1[, 1],
                list(var1 = as.name(paste0(dfName, "A")))))

> dfA
  v1 a b  c
A  A 5 4 10
B  B 7 2  9
```

And finally make it a matrix :

```
assign(paste0(dfName, "A"), get(paste0(dfName, "A")) %>% select(-1) %>% as.matrix())

> dfA
  a b  c
A 5 4 10
B 7 2  9
```

So, I can make it work, but it is not "pretty" to me...

Are there too much `assign()` or too much `eval(substitute())` ?
Is it the good way for doing it ?

I think I almost put the finger on it, but I still don't understand the errors I can have.

Do I miss something ? Is there a better way of doing it ? (by better, I mean clear coding, better efficiency, respect of R coding rules...)

Thanks a lot for your answers, and sorry for this long post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `standard evaluation` version of those function:

```
assign(paste0(dfName, "A"), get(paste0(dfName, "A")) %>%
           spread_(key = 'v2', value = paste0(dfName, "A")))
```

Note the `_` at the end of the verb, and the fact that `"v2"` is quoted.

From `dplyr` vignette:

> Standard evaluation basics
>
> Every function in dplyr that uses NSE also has a version that uses SE.
>   The name of the SE version is always the NSE name with an _ on the
>   end. For example, the SE version of summarise() is summarise_(); the
>   SE version of arrange() is arrange_(). These functions work very
>   similarly to their NSE cousins, but their inputs must be “quoted”:

Comment: Hmmm, I see ! I knew it for `dplyr`, but not for `tidyr`. And as it worked for `dplyr::select()` (without `_`), I didn't understand why it didn't work with `tidyr::spread()`. Thank you for your answer it helped me !

Answer (score 3):

**1) Map** Normally it is better to create a list of objects so using the input in the Note at the end and making use of `xtabs` try this.

No packages were used.

```
fun <- function(nm) xtabs(df[c(nm, head(names(df), 2))])
L <- Map(fun, tail(names(df), -2))
names(L) <- sub("df", "", names(L))  # optional - remove "df" from names
```

giving (continued after output):

```
> L
$A
   v2
v1  a b c
  A 3 8 4
  B 7 6 1

$B
   v2
v1   a  b  c
  A  6  9  5
  B  4 10  3

$C
   v2
v1   a  b  c
  A  7  6  1
  B 10  2  8
```

**2) reshape** Another possibility is to create a 3d table by reshaping `df` to long form and then using `xtabs` on that.

The long form will have one row for each cell in `dfA`, `dfB` and `dfC` and two new columns:

- The new `"vnames"` column contains the numeric values in the original `"dfA"`, `"dfB"`, `"dfC"` columns.  The `v.names` and `varying` arguments to `reshape` defines this.
- The new `"Group"` column identifies which column of `df` each value in the `"vnames"` column comes from.  The `timevar` and `times` arguments define this.

This approach has the advantage of making it easy to look at all slices.  For example, try each of these:
`tab["B", "b", "C"]`, `tab[,"b", "C"]`, `tab["B", "b", ]`, `tab["B",,"C"]`, `tab["B",,]`, `tab[,"b",]`, `tab[,,"C"]`

No packages are used.

```
vnames <- tail(names(df), -2)  # c("dfA", "dfB", "dfC")
long <- reshape(df, dir = "long", 
  varying = vnames, v.names = "vnames",
  times = sub("df", "", vnames), timevar = "Group")
tab <- xtabs(vnames ~ v1 + v2 + Group, long)
```

giving:

```
> tab
, , Group = A

   v2
v1   a  b  c
  A  3  8  4
  B  7  6  1

, , Group = B

   v2
v1   a  b  c
  A  6  9  5
  B  4 10  3

, , Group = C

   v2
v1   a  b  c
  A  7  6  1
  B 10  2  8
```

**2a) reshape2::melt** This variation uses `melt` from the reshape2 package in place of `reshape` in the base of R and is substantially more compact:

```
library(reshape2)

xtabs(value ~ v1 + v2 + variable, data = melt(df))
```

**Note:** Setting the seed for reproducibility we used this input as `df`:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)),
                 v2 = c(rep(letters[1:3], 2)),
                 dfA = sample(1:10, 6),
                 dfB = sample(1:10, 6),
                 dfC = sample(1:10, 6))
```

Comment: I'm impressed by this efficiency ! Thank you ! I did not know xtabs and Map. Then the only things left are my evaluation problems.

Comment: You're parsing and processing skills are unparalleled. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without converting to `list` with `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple columns as `value.var`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), v1 ~v2, value.var = c("dfA", "dfB", "dfC"))
#   v1 dfA_a dfA_b dfA_c dfB_a dfB_b dfB_c dfC_a dfC_b dfC_c
#1:  A     3     8     4     6     9     5     7     6     1
#2:  B     7     6     1     4    10     3    10     2     8
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)),
                  v2 = c(rep(letters[1:3], 2)),
                  dfA = sample(1:10, 6),
                  dfB = sample(1:10, 6),
                  dfC = sample(1:10, 6))
```